# plot Histogram with shaded area and without common borders in R

Tags: r, plot, histogram

I'm trying to draw a histogram with a shaded area (between 2 X values), but without the vertical common lines (lines between breaks) and with a abline. I have the following example code:

```
x<-rnorm(n=100, m=0, sd=1)
h<- hist(x, breaks=50)
cuts<- cut(h$breaks, c(-1, 1))
plot(h, col="green"[cuts])
abline(v=mean(x), lty=2, lwd=2)`
```

thank you very much, in advance.

Comment: If you plot with `border="green"[cuts]` you'll get solid green bars with no obvious divisions, but you'll lose the overall outline at the top of the histogram which you probably want to keep. I reckon the only way to keep that is work it out from the bin data and use `lines`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (follows from your creation of `h`):

```
np = length(h$breaks)
x = c(h$breaks[1],rep(h$breaks[-c(1,np)],rep(2,(np-2))), h$breaks[np])
y=rep(h$counts,rep(2,length(h$counts)))
```

Now x and y are the "skyline" coordinates. Try this:

```
plot(h)
lines(x,y, col="red", lwd=2)
```

So for your plot:

```
# make the plot
plot(h)
# fill the area with green fill and green outline
plot(h, col="green"[cuts], border="green"[cuts],add=TRUE)
# restore the skyline
lines(x,y)
abline(v=mean(x), lty=2, lwd=2)
```

Giving:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I used a much more crude approach. I create two histograms, and then, I overlap them.

```
h <- hist(x, breaks=50, plot=FALSE)
cuts <- cut(h$breaks, c(-1, 1))
plot(h$breaks, c(h$counts,0) ,type="s",col="black", lwd=2)
plot(h, col="gray"[cuts], lty="blank", add=T)
abline(v=mean(x), lty=2, lwd=2)
```

[image]